# Proper way to construct a Test object with a mutable member variable

Tags: java, string, mutable

What would be the proper way to construct a Test object with a member variable `testName`?

I want to support the ability to set the value of this attribute when it is constructed, and allow it to be mutable via a setter methods:

```
public class Test {
    private String testName;

    public Test( String name ) {
        this.testName = name;
    }

    public setTestName( String name ) {
        this.testName = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create objects, you call their *constructor*. In your case, that's `Test(String name)`:

```
Test myTestObject = new Test("and you must provide a string as a parameter");
```

now, because of the implementation of the constructor (`this.testName = name;`), the object's member value of `testName` will be `"and you must provide a string as a parameter"`.

Then you can set it to something different using the setter in the class:

```
myTestObject.setTestName("here you also need to provide a string as a parameter");
```

This way, when the object is constructed, there's some value in `testName`, and after that it is changed to something else.

This outlines how you can change the value of `testName` whenever you want, and to whatever you want. All you need to do is pass the wanted string as a parameter to the function.

You can read some more info [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: You're welcome!. If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted to help future readers know it worked for you.